# Access or SQL: Need help returning data from a field whose field name is dynamically chosen in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a legacy database in SQL set up like a spreadsheet with 50 columns.  Apart from employee names, the field names would be Machine01, Machine02, etc. and the records would include the date certified on each machine.  I am using Access as a legacy front end because there is already so much already coded and staff trained with it.

How would I go about writing a query that would provide the dates each person is certified on, say, Machine27?
In Access, I initially had

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName,  Forms![F: Reports Switchboard]![Machine Name]  As Expr1
FROM Certifications
WHERE  Forms![F: Reports Switchboard]![Machine Name]>""
```

But this provides a column filled with the machine name, not the dates in the field with that name.

I tried a number of other methods including a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_CertDate
    @fieldvar1 varchar(20)
AS      
    SELECT LastName, FirstName,  @fieldvar1
    FROM Certifications
    WHERE  Forms![F: Reports Switchboard]![Machine Name]>""  
GO
```

But again, I just get the field name in the query, not the record data for the field.

I think I am missing something obvious, but I need a push in the right direction.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In a regular database, you can't do this.. You'd do something like `SELECT x, y, CASE WHEN @fieldvar1 = 'A' THEN columnA WHEN @fieldvar1 = 'B' THEN ColumnB END...` . Access is wacky, but I'm not sure it's so massively departed that it'll allow you to parameterize an identifier..

Comment: What is the backend db? Add appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table and Field names cannot be dynamic in Access query object.

I will assume there is a unique identifier field something like EmpID. If there isn't, there should be.

Possible options:

1. every machine field would have same criteria with OR operator - 50 fields might hit limit on number of OR operators, apparently there is a limit of 99 AND operators
2. build a UNION query to rearrange machine fields to normalized structure and use that query as source for another query to do search - UNION has a limit of 50 SELECT lines so might just barely work and there is no builder or wizard for UNION, must type or copy/paste in SQLView

```
SELECT EmpID, LastName, FirstName, Machine01 AS CertDate, "Machine01" AS MachineName FROM Certifications
UNION SELECT EmpID, LastName, FirstName, Machine02, "Machine02" FROM Certifications
...;
```

3. use DLookup domain aggregate function on designated machine field, reference form control for field argument input

```
SELECT EmpID, LastName, FirstName, Forms![F: Reports Switchboard]![Machine Name] AS MachineName, 
DLookup("[" & Forms![F: Reports Switchboard]![Machine Name] & "]", "Certifications", "EmpID=" & [EmpID]) AS CertDate 
FROM Certifications;
```

4. VBA and QueryDefs to modify query object

Answer (score 1):

Since the machine name is a column of table, it is a structural component of the SQL statement and not string literal. Hence, you need to create a dynamic query object which you can handle in VBA using QueryDefs:

```vb
Dim qDef As QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT LastName, FirstName, "  _
         &       "[" & Forms![F: Reports Switchboard]![Machine Name] & "] As MachineDate " _
         & "FROM Certifications " _
         & "WHERE [" &  Forms![F: Reports Switchboard]![Machine Name] & "] >'' "

Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")   ' LOCATE SAVED QUERY
qdef.SQL = strSQL                                ' CHANGE ITS SQL
Set qdef = Nothing                               ' RELEASE OBJECT TO SAVE
```

But ideally if you can avoid wide formatted data since you never want to save data elements in column headers. As one DBA guru says, *[Why would you need to create a table with even 20 columns, let alone 2000 ???](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3976)*.

Instead use a more normalized, long table format and avoid complex queries:

| LastName | FirstName | Machine | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Stacks | Rick | Machine01 | 5/1/21 |
| Stacks | Rick | Machine02 | 5/15/21 |
| Stacks | Rick | Machine03 | 5/20/21 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Doing so, requires no VBA but a single, static SQL query:

```sql
SELECT LastName, FirstName, Machine, [Date]
FROM Certifications
WHERE Machine = Forms![F: Reports Switchboard]![Machine Name]
```